# When was the "do form" introduced in the English language?

Tags: verbs, old-english, do

The following might be standard textbook question, but not being a native speaker I am unaware of the origin.

In ancient English, as well as in other Germanic languages, questions were posed exchanging the position of subject and verb, a structure that still holds nowadays for auxiliary and modal verbs.

Examples:

- why speakest thou?
- how goes it?

whereas nowadays such ordinary verbs require the "do" as in *"why do you speak?"* and *"how does it go?"*, respectively. Likewise for the negative forms, that used to be defined accompanying the verb with the negative *not* (as in *speak not of the subject* and similars).

*When was the "do form" introduced in the English language (and how come)?*